# I want to upload 1 file and clone to 3 files and how do I upload multiple file sizes to the server using multer in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

This is temp, how to resize image before upload using multer

```
class Resize {
  constructor(folder) {
    this.folder = folder;
  }
  async save(files) {
    let filenames = [];
    for(let file of files){
      let filename = Resize.filename();
      let filepath = this.filepath(filename);
      await sharp(file.buffer)
        .resize(500, 500, { // size image 300x300
          fit: sharp.fit.inside,
          withoutEnlargement: true
        })
        .toFile(filepath);
      filenames.push(filename);
    }
    return filenames;
  }
  static filename() {
    // random file name
    return `${uuidv4()}.png`;
  }
  filepath(filename) {
    return path.resolve(`${this.folder}/${filename}`)
  }
}
```

This is temp, how to handle resize multi files or option multer for resize file before upload

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: It's same https://github.com/amazon-archives/serverless-image-resizing, query size 300x300 its response size image size 300x300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really resize a file before uploading it.

Comment: It's same github.com/amazon-archives/serverless-image-resizing, query size 300x300 its response size image size 300x300

Comment: You hot to be clear about your question. resizing a file generally means compression and stuff. But resizing  an image in terms of dimension means a different thing.